# Global file variable inaccessible outside function (Python)

Tags: python, file, io, global-variables

The variable log opens the file with a timestamp when the button is pressed, and should be closed when the button is off.
However, I cannot close the file opened in another function, even when the file has been declared as global. I tried putting "global file" outside of both functions, but that did not work.

```
 if button_status==True: #Press start
    if First_run==True: #Start a new logfile
        global log
        log=open(Fname,'a')
        log.writelines(header)
        First_run=False

     #Other code here

if button_status==False:#press stop
    log.close()
    First_run=True
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to just put something like `log = True` near the top of the file so that it is declared, outside of any methods or classes. Then get rid of the `global log` lines, and it should be accessible everywhere.

Comment: Looks like it is trying to close before ever opening at all, you can do a Try/Except there to get around it, or test for the variable type of `log`. Is `button_status` set to False during initialization?

Comment: Yes, it is. We will need try/except

Comment: fixed it by opening and closing when the button is not pressed with Fname being a global variable. log=open(Fname,'a')
        log.close()

Answer (score 0):

`global` is needed when you are refering to the variable outside a function.

```
log = False
if button_status==True: #Press start
if First_run==True: #Start a new logfile
    global log
    log=open(Fname,'a')
    log.writelines(header)
    First_run=False

 #Other code here

if button_status==False:#press stop
    global log
    log.close()
    First_run=True
```

Comment: are those 3 `if`s locates in a function declaration?

Comment: fixed it by opening and closing when the button is not pressed with Fname being a global variable. log=open(Fname,'a') log.close()